# Spellbook Codes?

Tags: pixel-kingdom

I am playing Pixel Kingdom on my iPad Mini. I went through the tutorial and notice something called the spellbook. It features 3 buttons: One with fire, one with thunder, and one with water. I typed in a random combination and it told me that it was an *invalid code*. So, what is the code or codes, and what do they unlock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from the [Pixel Kingdom Spell Book blog](http://pixel-kingdom-spell-book.blogspot.com/) and from the [Pixel Kingdom Wiki](http://pixelkingdom.wikia.com/wiki/SpellBook).  There are 8 codes altogether, and each give a different reward.

First I will tell you what is being unlocked, then the combination to unlock them.

### Dragoon Unit

[image]
Information:The dragoon unit can be unlocked using this combination:

**FIRE FIRE FIRE THUNDER FIRE**

### 5000 Gold and 5 Gem

**THUNDER THUNDER THUNDER THUNDER WATER**

### 7500 Gold and 10 Gem

**FIRE THUNDER THUNDER THUNDER WATER**

### 5000 Gold

**FIRE WATER WATER FIRE FIRE**

### 1500 Gold

**WATER THUNDER THUNDER THUNDER WATER**

### Undead army

The Undead Army is technically a skin-changer. It will make your units appear "undead." Here is the combination:

**THUNDER FIRE FIRE FIRE FIRE (can be deactivated at any time)**

### Disable ADS

You might as well agree with this: a players worst enemy is the ads that continually pop up on applications. You will never have to deal with this again if you put in this combination:

**WATER WATER WATER WATER WATER THUNDER THUNDER WATER**

### 300,000 Gold & 150 Gem

**WATER THUNDER WATER WATER FIRE WATER FIRE**

Answer (score -2):

Tapping any of the elements exactly one hundred times will give you the ??? Character

Comment: Do you have a citation or link to a page that describes this? I ask because this sounds like one of those rumors that flies around, and I'd hate for you to get downvoted just because of how your answer is written. Feel free to flag this comment as obsolete once you've linked a source. (Also, welcome to Arquade! Wander by the [tour] when you have a moment; we're not quite the same as a regular forum.)